# MATLAB: finding a row index in a matrix

Tags: matrix, matlab

I have a matrix and I want to find the maximum value in each column, then find the index of the row of that maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = magic(5)

A =

    17    24     1     8    15
    23     5     7    14    16
     4     6    13    20    22
    10    12    19    21     3
    11    18    25     2     9

[~,colind] = max(max(A))

colind =

     3
```

returns `colind` as the column index that contains the maximum value. If you want the row:

```
[~,rowind] = max(A);
max(rowind)

ans =

    5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fairly simple code to do this.

```
MaximumVal=0
for i= i:length(array)
   if MaximumVal>array(i)
      MaximumVal=array(i);
      Indicies=i;
   end
end
MaximumVal
Indicies
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html).  You can output the row and column of the maximum element immediately without invoking `max` twice as per your question.  As such, do this:

```
%// Define your matrix
A = ...;

% Find row and column location of where the maximum value is
[maxrow,maxcol] = find(A == max(A(:)));
```

Also, take note that if you have multiple values that share the same maximum, this will output **all** of the rows and columns in your matrix that share this maximum, so it isn't just limited to one row and column as what `max` will do.